# My PC is not reachable on local LAN after changing computer name

Tags: windows, networking, lan, workgroup

My PC is not reachable on my local LAN (workgroup) after changing the computer name. I then renamed it back to the original name and it is still not reachable.

Pinging other computers from mine is successful. However, other computers can't ping me or access my shared folders.

What do you suggest in that case?

Comment: are you part of the same workgroup, domain, or use the same gateway?\

Answer (score 0):

The other computers may have dns entries cached. This would be one reason why your PC can see others, but not the other way around.

One thing you will want to try is a dns flush on the other computers. If these are windows machines, you will want to go to start / run / cmd.  Once at the command prompt type ipconfig /flushdns .

Is the hostname the only thing that was changed? Are there any new firewall programs installed, or the Windows firewall enabled?

Comment: IMO, computers in a Windows workgroup do not require DNS for identification and communication. They are using NetBIOS names. Were computers required DNS to communicate in a workgroup, that would have made impossible inter-process communication inside the same computer, i.e. functioning of isolated computer at all (without setting a local DNS server on a workstation first)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that changing computer (or workgroup) name makes computer unreachable by its ip-address.

Returning a computer the previous name never recovers the same computer SID, i.e. after getting the same name the identification of computer is different.
All users in a workgroup are identified as (computer ID)\username and so, effectively, they and access to any network shared resource (service, file, etc.) under those IDs (accounts, users) were reset.

I would reboot computer after changing computer (or user/account) name and reset/reinstall anew any network shared resource (network printers, network shares, shared network services, etc.) that depend on any such usernames with corresponding reboot on any other computers.

IMO, such changes require some time to propagate and are not immediate and require up to 2 hours to be known by (sychronized at) other computers in workgroup